Is there a usable substitute for USING PERIODIC COMMIT in Neo4j/Cypher?
I'm running Neo4j Community Edition on Linux, and I'm having major issues loading from CSV files. The total size of the files is < 2GB for the nodes, and about 2GB for the relationships. I'm well under the node limit for Neo4j Community.
My code is very simple, and looks like this:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///node_file.csv" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (:enc {csn: toInteger(csvLine.csn)})
;

I'm running into memory issues, where my < 4GB overall data is getting bloated into over 200GB (!) inside Neo4j, and I still have not successfully loaded all my data.
The old syntax of USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 generates this error in Cypher/Neo4j 5.22 (at least):
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: The PERIODIC COMMIT query hint is no longer supported. Please use CALL { ... } IN TRANSACTIONS instead. (line 5, column 7 (offset: 153))
"USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000"
       ^}

ChatGPT suggests using the apoc library. Unfortunately, it's very non-obvious how to use the apoc library in Neo4j Community Edition. It doesn't appear to be enabled, and un-commenting this line in neo4j.conf:
dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*

does absolutely nothing to enable me to run anything like CALL apoc.periodic.iterate. I still get error messages saying Neo4j doesn't have apoc installed.
[EDIT] I've also downloaded the appropriate extended jar file for apoc, put it in the plugins directory, and otherwise done stuff like in this post, but no joy.
Am I missing something? What is a workable alternative to USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000?

Starting with neo4j 5.0, USING PERIODIC COMMIT is no longer supported. Instead, you should use CALL subqueries in transactions.
For example, do this for your use case:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///node_file.csv" AS csvLine
FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CALL {
  WITH csvLine
  CREATE (:enc {csn: toInteger(csvLine.csn)})
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS


Will that work when I'm using the Python neo4j module? It says it only works for implicit transactions.

Yes. "Implicit" or auto-commit transactions are documented to work for IN TRANSACTIONS. You just have to use Session.run to execute the query. Using an implicit transaction is required since IN TRANSACTIONS operation internally manages multiple transactions for you.

Ah, I see. Well, I'm running it now. The nodes all load, and it's using a LOT less RAM. Curious to see if the relationships load. If they do, I'll definitely accept your answer. Many thanks!

Is there a way to parallelize this to run a bit faster?

Yes, the ability to also run in parallel was added in neo4j 5.21: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/subqueries-in-transactions/#concurrent-transactions
